# Powershell error handling: do something if NO error occured

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I've been searching around for this but can't seem to find it. 
I'm having a script with a try {} catch {} statement. I'd like to add an action if NO error occured.

Eg

```
try { something }
catch { "Error occured" }
if (!error) {
"No Error Occured"
}
```

How can I test if no error occured in the statement?

Thanks in advance

Walter

Comment: Another option would be to just put the "no error" code after the statement in the try block: `try { something; "no error" } catch { "error" }`. If "something" fails with a terminating error, execution will skip over the "no error" code and enter the catch block. (Of course, the "no error" code might itself raise an exception, so this approach isn't always appropriate.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check the automatic-variable `$error` after you cleared it.

```
$error.clear()
try { something }
catch { "Error occured" }
if (!$error) { "No Error Occured" }
```

Comment: great! Thanks! I knew it had to be easy :)

Comment: I like this solution, but I think it would be much better to create a variable and use it in the  relevant `-ErrorVariable` parameters if you can. Using the global error stack and clearing it feels like it's bad practice or risks losing errors.

Answer (score 11):

Another way:

```
$ErrorOccured = $false

try 
{ 
   $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
   ...something...
}
catch
{
   "Error occured"
   $ErrorOccured=$true
}

if(!$ErrorOccured) {"No Error Occured"}
```

.

Comment: Don't forget to set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the head of the try block if you also want to catch non-terminating errors.  BTW this won't catch error codes returned from console exes.

Answer (score 5):

What about,

```
something
If ($?)
{
    "No error"
}
Else
{
    "Error"
}
```

This will work for non terminating errors too.