# Test if zip File extract command executed

Tags: powershell, if-statement, unzip, powershell-4.0

I want to test if condition for zip file got extracted properly or any error in extracting command in PowerShell v4. Please correct my code.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$file = 'C:\PSScripts\raw_scripts\zipfold\test.zip'
$path = 'C:\PSScripts\raw_scripts\zipfold\extract'

if ( (Test-path $file) -and (Test-path $path) -eq $True ) {
    if ((unzip $file $path)) {
        echo "done with unzip of file"
    } else {
        echo "can not unzip the file"
    }
} else {
    echo "$file or $path is not available"
}

function unzip {
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

    $return = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
    return $return
}
```

This script extract a zip file but displays "can not unzip file." as output.

Not sure what `$return` variable has as its value, my If condition is always getting fail.

Comment: My hunch says `ExtractToDirectory` does not have a return value so it is null

Comment: Thanks Matt, any other way we can achieve this, this will be very help full for me

Comment: A simple way to measure that with this method is to use a try block with  `$?` which contains $TRUE if the last operation succeeded and $FALSE if it failed. I'm saying I think you have to assume success based on lack of failure. Something _similar_ to what I was suggesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496885/powershell-error-handling-do-something-if-no-error-occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttodirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) confirms what @Matt was suspecting. `ExtractToDirectory()` is defined as a `void` method, so it doesn't return anything. Because of that `$return` is always `$null`, which evaluates to `$false`.

With that said, the method should throw exceptions if something goes wrong, so you could use `try`/`catch` and return `$false` in case an exception occurs:

```
function unzip {
  param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

  try {
    [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
    $true
  } catch {
    $false
  }
}
```